# Exception of sending email doesn't show in the CC.net Dashboard

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

All, I succeed to config a email publisher in the ccnet.config. and it works fine. all the task like build, unittest, merge result, etc are completed successfully. 
But for some reason. I mistake the smtp authentication user name which will cause a exception when run a build. By the way. I set the notifications is Always.

```
        <publishers>
            <statistics />
            <merge>
                <files>
                    <file>TestResult\UnitTestResults.trx</file>
                </files>
            </merge>

            <buildpublisher>
                <sourceDir>E:\study\cc.net\Test\KMIH\BackUpFolder\Source</sourceDir>
                <publishDir>E:\study\cc.net\Test\KMIH\BackUpFolder\Publish</publishDir>
                <useLabelSubDirectory>true</useLabelSubDirectory>
                <alwaysPublish>true</alwaysPublish>
            </buildpublisher>
            <email mailport="25" mailhostUsername="xxxxxx" mailhostPassword="xxxxxx" useSSL="FALSE" includeDetails="true">
                <from>xxxxx@163.com</from>
                <mailhost>smtp.163.com</mailhost>
                <users>
                    <user name="JoeWang" group="BuildMaster" address="xxxxx@163.com"/>
                </users>
                <groups>
                    <group name="BuildMaster">
                        <notifications>
                            <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
                        </notifications>
                    </group>
                </groups>
            </email>
            <xmllogger/>
            <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="50"/>
        </publishers>
```

So Hopefully I would like to see this error show up when I check the build report of Dashboard. I can see a failed build. But I didn't found any error message or information to let me know what exactly error it is. (In this case. it is wrong email configuration).

Am I missing something ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check out the Source Code. (1.8.5.0) . I think I found why..

It seems it is a CC.net bug. Hopefully it is not.

Here is the exception coming from `ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.TaskBase`.

```
public virtual void Run(IIntegrationResult result)
        {
            // Initialise the task
            this.WasSuccessful = false;
            if ((this.currentStatus == null) ||
                (this.currentStatus.Status != ItemBuildStatus.Running))
            {
                InitialiseStatus(ItemBuildStatus.Pending);
                currentStatus.Status = ItemBuildStatus.Running;
            }

            // Perform the actual run
            currentStatus.TimeOfEstimatedCompletion = CalculateEstimatedTime();
            currentStatus.TimeStarted = DateTime.Now;
            try
            {
                this.WasSuccessful = Execute(result);//Email sending exception is threw out...
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                // Store the error message
                currentStatus.Error = error.Message;
                result.Status = IntegrationStatus.Exception;
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up
                currentStatus.Status = (this.WasSuccessful) ? ItemBuildStatus.CompletedSuccess : ItemBuildStatus.CompletedFailed;
                currentStatus.TimeCompleted = DateTime.Now;

                switch (result.Status)
                {
                    case IntegrationStatus.Unknown:
                    case IntegrationStatus.Success:
                        result.Status = this.WasSuccessful ? IntegrationStatus.Success : IntegrationStatus.Failure;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

The Execute is a abstract function.

`protected abstract bool Execute(IIntegrationResult result);`

And the build log is built in the Class `XmlIntegrationResultWriter`

```
public void Write(IIntegrationResult result)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(Elements.CRUISE_ROOT);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("project", result.ProjectName);
            WriteRequest(result.IntegrationRequest);
            WriteModifications(result.Modifications);
            WriteIntegrationProperties(result);
            WriteBuildElement(result);
            WriteException(result);//since no exception found . so the log no exception detail populated. That is the root cause.
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

So I think the exception should added into IIntegrationResult like below when it happened.

```
try
            {
                this.WasSuccessful = Execute(result);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                // Store the error message
                result.ExceptionResult = error;//Add the exception in the build process so that it will be generated in the build log. 
                currentStatus.Error = error.Message;
                result.Status = IntegrationStatus.Exception;
                throw;
            }
```

I replaced the ccnet.exe with the new compiled one.  Then the exception will show in the build report of Dashboard.

Any better idea? Thanks.